# Reorder variant effects according to alternate column in vcf file

Tags: r, dplyr, vcf-vcard

I have a vcf file with a column of comma-separated variant alleles ("alt") and another column with their predicted effects ("info"). (See `dput()` structure below for an example dataframe.) However, for whatever reason, the variant effect prediction software outputs the effects in random order, instead of the same order the variants are listed in the "alt" column.

I would like to extract only certain information from each variant effect field (the real file has lots of information in this field that I don't need) and concatenate that information into a comma-separated string. However, first, the variant effects must be reordered according to their order in the "alt" column.

For example, row 2 in the below dataframe currently looks like this:

```
   alt    info
   T,G    G|intron,T|splice_site
```

where "G|intron" denotes that the effect of variant "G" is "intron". I would like the final output to just have the predicted effect, and be reordered to match the "alt" column, like this:

```
   alt    info
   T,G    splice_site,intron
```

This way, the first variant allele always matches the first predicted effect, and so on... The order can't just be reversed, because in some columns they are already in the correct order, or there may be three variants that are in random order, etc...

My thought was to turn "G|intron" into a "key|value" pair, and then reorder the keys according to the "alt" column, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. **I'm using piping to manipulate the dataframe in other ways, so the solution must work as part of a dplyr pipe.**

Example dataframe structure is:

```
var <- structure(list(chr = c("01", "01", "01", "01"), pos = c(10, 20, 
30, 40), ref = c("T", "A", "G", "C"), alt = c("A", "T,G", "A,C,T", 
"G"), info = c("A|missense|A2L", "G|intron,T|splice_site", "T|missense|V28R,A|missense|V28E,C|missense|V28L", 
"G|intergenic")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps not the most optimal (surely there's a way to get separate not to split the amino acid variants to stay with the change type, but I don't know it), but it will work for you.

The first few lines of code split the comma-separated strings into individual items. Instead of left_join'ing, you could sort them individually using `purrr::map(alt, ~ str_sort(.x))` or similar and then just unnesting, but joining (which uses a hash) will be faster for large data. And since we've set our x tibble as the portion that include the colum "alt", the joined tibble will be in that order. Then I'm using group_by and summarise to bring them back into a single string according to the coordinates (and the ref to keep it along).

```
library(tidyverse)
var %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(alt, info), ~ stringr::str_split(., ",")) %>% 
  left_join(
    x = {.} %>% select(-info) %>% unnest_legacy(),
    y = {.} %>% select(-alt) %>% unnest_legacy() %>% 
      separate(info, into = c("alt","info","aa_change"), sep = "\\|"),
    by = c("chr","pos","ref","alt")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(info = ifelse(is.na(aa_change),info, sprintf("%s|%s",info, aa_change))) %>% 
  group_by(
    chr, pos, ref
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    alt = paste(alt,collapse = ","),
    info = paste(info, collapse = ",")
    )
```

This produces the following:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   chr, pos [4]
  chr     pos ref   alt   info                                     
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>                                    
1 01       10 T     A     missense|A2L                             
2 01       20 A     T,G   splice_site,intron                       
3 01       30 G     A,C,T missense|V28E,missense|V28L,missense|V28R
4 01       40 C     G     intergenic
```

Of note in the above code, I'm using `{.}` in the join to make a copy of the piped tibble so I can modify it before joining, which is critical to this operation.